# Newtonsoft Json deserialization into specific types

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a class Action and many other specific classes that derive from this one like SendCoordinates, MakeCall, etc..

So given a JSON response like this one:

```
 {
      "action":{
          "type":"SendCoordinates",
          "data": "41°24'12.2 N 2°10'26.5"
       }
}
```

Now my question is regarding Newtonsoft json library. What is the best way to implement this ? Should I create specific JSON converters for each class like they show here http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm

Or should I go for a entirelly different aproach that I'm not considering ? Can you guys leave me your opinions on this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't valid JSON...

Comment: is `action` array or object?

Comment: @GeneR It's an object, its valid now, sorry !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Newtonsoft.Json you can deserialise to a type via the non-generic overload `DeserializeObject(string value, type type)`.

This means you can use the `Type` property as a hint to which type to deserialize.

1. deserialise to base type
2. get type name of actual `Action` object
3. get type of type full name
4. deserialise to derived action type

See the following example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace com.example.SO42736347
{
    public class Action
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Action1 : Action
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        public const string ACTION1 = @"{
            ""Type"" : ""com.example.Json.Action1"",
            ""Data"" : ""41°24'12.2 N 2°10'26.5""
        }";

        public static void Main()
        {
            var action = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action>(ACTION1);

            var type = Type.GetType(action.Type);

            var action1 = (Action1) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ACTION1, type);
        }

    }
}
```

If you do not want to specify the full qualified type name in the `Type` field, you can construct the FullName of the type by using custom programme logic (e.g. prefixing it with a base namespace).

**Edit**: according to the comments it should be able to deserialise a *list* of actions (of derived types). Therefore I appended the following example to my answer where you can see, how to deserialise a list of actions by doing the following:

1. deserialise to generic JArray
2. for each item in array determine the `Type` of the `Action`
3. deserialise into the specific derived type

I also added a loop after the conversion to show how to further process the converted actions.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace com.example.Json
{
    public class Action
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Action1 : Action
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Action2 : Action
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        public const string ACTION1 = @"{
        ""Type"" : ""com.example.Json.Action1"",
            ""Data"" : ""41°24'12.2 N 2°10'26.5""
        }";

        public const string ACTION2 = @"{
        ""Type"" : ""com.example.Json.Action2"",
            ""SomeProperty"" : ""arbitrary-value""
        }";

        public const string ACTIONS =  
            "[" + 
            ACTION1 +
            "," + 
            ACTION2 +
            "]" ;

        public static void Main()
        {

            var actions = new List<Action>();

            JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(ACTIONS);
            foreach(var item in jArray)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
                var baseAction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action>(json);
                var type = Type.GetType(baseAction.Type);
                var action = (Action) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);
                actions.Add(action);
            }

            // now that we have converted all array items into specific derived action objects
            // we can start processing them anyway we want
            // keep in mind that you have to check the runtime type in order to find out what
            // specific kind of action we have

            // eg.
            foreach(var action in actions)
            {
                switch(action.Type)
                {
                    case "com.example.Json.Action1":
                        // do something
                        Console.WriteLine("found com.example.Json.Action1");
                        Console.WriteLine((action as Action1).Data);
                        break;
                    case "com.example.Json.Action2":
                        // do something
                        Console.WriteLine("found com.example.Json.Action2");
                        Console.WriteLine((action as Action2).SomeProperty);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // do something
                        Console.WriteLine("found something else");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So this has to be a two step deserialization? Given your example I wanted that "var action" would already be of type Action1. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You can certainly resort to text parsing (or regex) the json text to find out the `type` property. But this approach is much more type safe and easy to troubleshoot (when having added some error checking).
If you really want to avoid having declared another variable you can make it more compact like this: `var action1 = (Action1) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ACTION1, Type.GetType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action>(ACTION1).Type));`, but this does not make it any more readable.
Is there any reason of not using two variables?

Comment: Yes , cause my main JSON response will be an array of actions and I will populate a view based on that information, like this: ` var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Actions); ` So is there a way to give JsonConvert the tools he needs to make this specific conversions automatic ?

Comment: this is not a problem either: deserialise into `List<Action>`. From there you iterate over the list and subsequently deserialise into the respective derived action types

Comment: Thanks!! Would you like to update your answer for me to mark it down as correct?

Comment: @Greggz I updated the answer and added more code to show how to convert a json response with a list of specific actions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137833/discussion-between-ronald-rink-d-fens-and-greggz).

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize it to `SomeObject`:

```
public class SomeObject
{
  public SomeAction Action { get; set; }
  public OtherAction Call { get; set; }
}
public class SomeAction
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Data { get; set; }
}
public class OtherAction { ... }
```

Possible `json` to deserialize:

```
{
  "action":{ "type":"SendCoordinates", "data": "41°24'12.2 N 2°10'26.5" }
}
```

or:

```
{
  "call":{ ... }
}
```

Comment: public SomeAction Action ? That's not making sense to me. Action is my base class. The field shoul'nt be just public Action ?

Comment: And my problem is how to make the decision to which type should I convert to

Comment: Then your `json` should look like `{ "type":"SendCoordinates", "data": "41°24'12.2 N 2°10'26.5" }`, then you can deserialize it to your `Action class`

Comment: And how to deserialize to my specific class ?

Comment: `var action = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeAction>(json)`

Comment: Okok, but I don't know the type SomeAction. Only at runtime I get the string with name of the type

Comment: if i got right, property `action` defines the type where it should be deserialized, then you can declare in `SomeObject` all possible classes and after deserialization one of them will be filled

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Would you like to update your answer for me to mark it as correct?

Comment: I'm sorry I think perhaps I have not explained myself right. The second possible json to deserialize should be { "action": { "type":"Call", ... } }